# How observe data from fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am observing whether user is signed in. If they're signed-in, then the navigation header `name` and `surname` should update.

Here is fragment of code. It works only in the activity class. I want to do same stuff but in the fragment but when I do it, it doesn't work.

```
fun updateUI(){

    println("Updating UI")
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()


    if(mAuth.currentUser!=null){


        database.child("users").child(mAuth.currentUser?.uid.toString()).addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    println("User found")
                    mutable_name.postValue(snapshot.child("name").value.toString())
                    mutable_surname.postValue(snapshot.child("surname").value.toString())
                } else {
                    println("User not found")
                    mutable_name.postValue("Guest")
                    mutable_surname.postValue("")
                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                println(error.message)
            }
        })
    }else{
        println("User not signed in")
        mutable_name.postValue("Guest")
        mutable_surname.postValue("")
    }

    name.observe(this, {
        user_name.text = it.toString()
    })

    surname.observe(this, {
       user_surname.text = it.toString()
    })   

}
```

I tried updating in fragments by creating instance of class and using this function but I cut this observers separately (with "this" on main and "`lifeCycleOwner`" on fragments) but doesn't work either.

How should I do it ?

Comment: do you have `user_name` & `user_surname` in fragment layout or activity layout ?

Comment: in activty layout i also use them like mainActivity.user_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `LoginFragment` you can't call methods in `MainActivity` by instantiating the activity this way

```
val mainActivity = MainActivity()
mainActivity.updateUI()
```

But you can call it by using `activity` and cast it to the `MainActivity`

```
(activity as MainActivity).updateUI()
```

Comment: should this make this updateUI work in fragment or what

Comment: this will be called from the fragment; but as both fragment and the hosting activity are `onResume` state, then it doesn't matter, or it depends on your needed design, if there are multiple fragments that will call `updateUI()`, then keep it in the activity to avoid code repetition